# Windows Active Directory Home Folders

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Are Home Folders as configured in AD Users and Computers any different to simply creating a mapped drive through GPO Preferences to H:?

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind that are minor differences.

When you use the "home folder" in their AD profile:

1) it could be a little easier to setup folder redirection

2) their default "home" when opening a command prompt is that drive mapping

That's about the only thing I can think of, whether you consider them pros or cons is up to you.